# Gatsby project Github problem "Everting up-to-date."

Tags: git, terminal, gatsby, github-for-mac

MacBook-Pro:gatsby_spec NP$ git status

On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

MacBook-Pro:gatsby_spec NP$ git push origin master

Everything up-to-date

I have solved the problems I experienced by doing a revert in Git. But now I always get the message Everting up-to-date.

Also when I do changes in the files the status display red, I put git add . to make it ready for the push. But the push stay on Everything up-to-date.

Can someone help me with this? Let me know if any other information is needed. I have searched on Google a lot and try all the pages in the results. But nothing does help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By executing `add .` you **stage** the files and they are ready to be **committed** not ready to be **pushed**. So you first have to commit your changes locally `git commit -m 'some message'` and then execute `git push`

Comment: In my currently post I have the details in my new post. I try so much that I forgot to commit. My bigger problem is to build with gatsby build. @TenorFlyy  I don't know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I have no suggestions, I am completely unfamiliar with the project. You would be better of if you post a new question regarding that issue, this one was purely git problem :)